# Multiple Markers on a Google Map

Tags: google-maps

How can I map these lat long values on maps.google.com without having to get driving directions? I want these lat/long values to be 3 markers (A,B,C) on a google map. I don't intend to do any coding for this.

This is what I have currently:

[http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=34.90127866,-120.44880259&daddr=34.8902896,-120.43227+to:34.90134564,-120.44887781](http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=34.90127866,-120.44880259&daddr=34.8902896,-120.43227%20to:34.90134564,-120.44887781)

Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with maps.google.com. However, you can make a new map using My Maps (http://www.google.com/maps/mm) and add three points very easily. You can then either embed it with an iframe or link to it directly.

Answer (score 5):

It is definitely possible to do this without using the map maker. You simply have to use the Google Maps API. Using mm means you have to go back to the map maker each and every time you want to add a marker. The API on the other hand offers you the versatility to do anything you may need and all on the fly.

[API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)

Comment: The question states: "I don't intend to do any coding for this". In my opinion, that rules out the API.

Comment: …then what is it doing on StackOverflow?